# Sort order of output when using sed and iterating in folder

Tags: grep, sed

I am using the following sed command to find a string in between patters for each file in a folder, files are named 01.txt, 02.txt etc.:

```
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/PAT1/!{/PAT2/!p}}' * >> file
```

but the output is not sorted by the same order of files in the directory, rather by some other order. I did try to pipe out to sort but the order is then spread across ALL matches/All files which is not what I am looking for. I want the output to be appended in the same 01.txt, 02.txt order. I've seen grep doing the same, finding matches and jumping from one file to another. I prefer using sed but grep is an option.
thanks.

Comment: try sorting the output with `sort` command. maybe you want to run sort, after you generate your file, IDK.  `man sort` will give you some more options. Posting a sample of your input, or output could be useful to us, if you want something sorted in a more specific way.

Comment: @j0h i did use 'sort' se my question above

Answer (score 0):

Had to resort to a script, still one line:

`for f in file*.txt; do sed -n 'PAT1/,/PAT2/{/PAT1!{/PAT2};}' $f >> outputfile; done`